# quicksort logic is not working properly

Tags: c, quicksort

Following is the code for quicksort, i made..but there is something wrong,which gives me wrong output. For an integer array [65,70,75,80,85,60,55,50,45], output i am getting is 
[45 50 55 65 60 70 75 80 85], which obviously is wrong.

```
int partition(int *b,int r,int s)
{
    int pivot=b[r];
    int i,j;
    i=r;
    j=s;
    while(i<=j)
    {
        while(b[i]<=pivot)
            i++;
        while(b[j]>=pivot)
            j--;
        if(i<j)
        {
            int temp;
            temp=b[i];
            b[i]=b[j];
            b[j]=temp;
        }
    }
    b[r]=b[j];
    b[j]=pivot;
    return j;
}
void quicksort(int *a,int p,int q)
{

    if(p<q)
    {
        int j;
        j=partition(a,p,q);
        quicksort(a,p,j-1);
        quicksort(a,j+1,q);

    }
}
int main()
{
    int arr[9]={65,70,75,80,85,60,55,50,45};
    quicksort(arr,0,8);
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone suggest my mistake?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the standard [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) function?

Comment: You should write a function to test if the partition is working as expected rather than hoping everything would work.

Comment: And please, fix the indent.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that you're not going out of bounds.
Also I think you should use strict comparison. Your current code will not be able to sort `[1, 2]` (the last swap will mess it up).

The last swap seems a bit arbitrary, it should not be needed.